# How to get a tiled type on the mapLayer in Phaser

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, phaser-framework

I created a map with Tiled and loaded it from JSON in a Phaser game, and everything works well.

Now I would like to get a type of a tile on certain point x,y from the map layer. I couldn't find any function for this. My only idea was to read the JSON data on my own and create a 2d array for further use.

Answer (score 1):

Phaser's Tilemap contains method `getTile(x,y,layer,notNull)` that returns tile object from certain point BUT given in tile units, not pixels.

Then I believe that `index` property of `Phaser.tile` contains data you need (see [here](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Tile.html)).

All you need to do is convert pixels to tile units - basically you may just div Pixels by Tile width or height (see properties description [here](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Tilemap.html#tileHeight)). So for default 32/32 grid pixels 0-31 are 1 title, 32-61 are 2nd title, and so on.

Comment: Thx, I saw this funciton, but did't know the index is the tile type.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me:

```
var map = this.cache.getTilemapData('testmap').data.layers[0].data;
```